# manual compiling doozerd fails

Tags: compilation, go

I installed doozerd sources in:

```
home/stephan/src/go/src/pkg/github.com/ha/doozerd
```

$GOROOT = /home/stephan/src/go
$GOPATH = /home/stephan/src/go/src/pkg/

When I try to do ./all.sh in the doozerd checkout from github I get package could not be found locally errors.. :

```
.
    imports github.com/ha/doozerd/peer
    imports github.com/ha/doozerd/web
    imports code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket: /home/stephan/src/go/src/pkg/github.com/ha/doozerd/web/web.go:4:2: package could not be found locally
.
    imports github.com/ha/doozerd/peer
    imports github.com/ha/doozerd/consensus
    imports code.google.com/p/goprotobuf/proto: /home/stephan/src/go/src/pkg/github.com/ha/doozerd/server/conn.go:4:2: package could not be found locally
.
    imports github.com/ha/doozer: /home/stephan/src/go/src/pkg/github.com/ha/doozerd/peer/peer.go:4:2: package could not be found locally
```

I thought go would find the missing requirements, and install them itself.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$GOPATH =

`/home/stephan/src/go/src/pkg/` means the go tool looks for packages in 
`/home/stephan/src/go/src/pkg/src/<import-path>`, but you've put the sources in `/home/stephan/src/go/src/pkg/github.com/ha/doozerd` instead.